# JSDOM script element being overwritten in Mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, global, jsdom

I have two nearly identical JS files that I cannot change that I want to add tests for.

file 1:

```js
const url = "https://file-1.js";

(function () {
  "use strict";
  window.onload = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  };
})();
```

file 2:

```js
const url = "https://file-2.js";

(function () {
  "use strict";
  window.onload = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  };
})();
```

Then test 1:

```js
const chai = require("chai");
const { expect } = chai;
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const { window } = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><p>Fake document</p>`, {
  resources: "usable",
});

global.document = window.document;
global.window = window;

const myFile = require("../src/myFile");

describe("Test 1", function () {
    it("Loads a file from an external source", function (done) {
      console.log(window.document.head.children); // See what's going on
      expect(window.document.head.children[0].src).to.equal("https://file-1.js");
    });
});
```

test 2:

```js
const chai = require("chai");
const { expect } = chai;
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const myFile2 = require("../src/myFile2");

describe("Test 2", function () {
    it("Loads a file from an external source", function (done) {
      console.log(window.document.head.children); // See what's going on
      expect(window.document.head.children[0].src).to.equal("https://file-2.js");
    });
});
```

Test 2 passes but test 1 fails. The value of both console.logs is:

```
HTMLCollection { '0': HTMLScriptElement {} }
```

And `console.log(window.document.head.children[0].src)` produces:

```
https://file-2.js
```

I'd expect there to be two children in `window.document.head` but there's only 1, per the above. It appears Mocha is loading all the required files in all tests first, and the appendChild in the 2nd file is overwriting the value from the first.

Is there a way around this? I experimented with `done()` or moving around where the require is called but it results in the same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the repo in the answer from Christian I realized I needed to fire the `window.onload` event after importing each file.

Also, I do not want to run ('dangerously') the scripts, just ensure that they are appended a document as a script element. That's all.

The following works:

```js
const chai = require("chai");
const { expect } = chai;
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const { window } = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><p>Fake document</p>`, {
  resources: "usable",
});

global.document = window.document;
global.window = window;

const downloaderPopup = require("../src/MyFile");
window.dispatchEvent(new window.Event("load"));
const downloaderMain = require("../src/MyFile2");
window.dispatchEvent(new window.Event("load"));

describe("Both tests", function () {
  describe("Test 1", function () {
    it("Dynamocally loads file 1", function () {
      expect(window.document.head.children[1].src).to.equal("https://file-1.js");
    });
  });
  describe("Test 2", function () {
    it("Dynamically loads file 2", function () {
      expect(window.document.head.children[0].src).to.equal("https://file-2.js");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If you don't know what those scripts will contain, you can probably do `downloaderPopup = ...; if(window.onload) window.onload(); delete window.onload;` for each script (since it's only manually setting `window.onload` that is an issue here), and then fire the *actual* load event once all of your "preprocessing" is done with `window.dispatchEvent`. I only mention this because you might end up needing scripts that don't behave as expected and this paradigm might save you headaches.

Answer (score 0):

[I created a repo for you to look at.](https://github.com/christiantjl/JSDOM-debugging) A few notes:

1. We need to set the `runScripts: "dangerously"` flag for JSDOM if we want to load external scripts (see [this issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1914)).
2. We need to manually re-fire the `load` event ourselves - basically, by the time your script is executed, the status of `document.readyState` is `"complete"`, i.e., the `load` event has already fired.

   What's happening here is that `window` is ready as soon as JSDOM is done compiling the HTML script we pass it on initialization. We can import what we need and then **fire the `load` event manually** - as long as we do not pass any scripts to the initial JSDOM call, we can be sure that we will not be triggering anything twice.
3. When the load event fires, the generated `<script>` tags are actually added to the DOM, but since they contain dummy URLs with nothing to actually load, the process throws: `Error: Could not load script: "https://file-1.js/"`. I changed those URLs to the jQuery library and Hammer.js for the sake of testing, and you will need to add logic to make sure that URL is safe.
4. Since both scripts set `window.onload = function() {...}`, if we run them both and then fire the `load` event (which we would normally do), only the last one will be triggered because each `window.onload` set overwrites the former.

   We can get around this, but only because we know what the script contains. See the test files for the workaround: just `require`, fire the onload, and then use `delete window.onload`. I used `dispatchEvent` just to show the form for that, but since the overwrite issue isn't a problem for `window.addEventListener` (just for naively setting the `window.onload` property), it would probably be better to call `window.onload()` and then deleting it. It's hairy but it's not unmanageable.

I have actually been working on something close to this for the past few days, and have recently put up two packages to help with similar scenarios: **[enable-window-document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enable-window-document)** (which exposes `window` and `document` globals) and **[enable-browser-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enable-browser-mode)** (which aims to completely simulate the browser runtime, setting the `global` object to `window` and exposing a `window.include` function to evaluate an imported script in the global context, i.e. `include('jquery.min.js')`, with no errors).

For this situation (and the low complexity of the test scripts), **enable-window-document** will suffice. When running in full browser compatibility mode, we actually get failures because of the `const url = ...` declaration in both scripts - those are evaluated in the global context when full browser compatibility is enabled, which results in trying to re-set the `window.url` variable which is declared as `const`. Simply setting the `window` and `document` globals *will* work for this use case, but if you start to load complex scripts you may run into issues.

What I would recommend is to use `enable-browser-mode` if your scripts could run in the browser (i.e., no conflicting global `const` variables), and then replace any `require` calls to browser JS (`test1.js` and `test2.js`) with `include()`. This will make sure that window refers to the global object and your average wild browser JS will execute as expected.

After loading all the scripts and hacking around the `onload` conflicts, we run the tests:

```
// inside index.js
...
console.log(document.head.outerHTML);
console.log("jQuery:", window.$);
```

```
$ node .

RUNNING TESTS...
<head><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script></head>
jQuery: undefined
```

And weirdly we can't access `window.jQuery` at runtime. Yet, in the console:

```
$ node

Welcome to Node.js v14.4.0.
Type ".help" for more information.

> require('.')
RUNNING TESTS...
<head><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script></head>
jQuery: undefined
{}

> window.jQuery
<ref *1> [Function: S] {
  fn: S {
    jquery: '3.5.1',
    constructor: [Circular *1],
    length: 0,
    toArray: [Function: toArray]
    ...
```

So I would recommend toying around to see what you can and cannot get to work.

Footnote: Jest is hot Facebook garbage and I'm not going to concern myself with debugging it (claims `window` global doesn't exist in `myFile.js` and so on). What we're doing here is pretty hacky and seems out of the suite's scope, or else conflicts with its native JSDOM interfacing somehow, though I might be missing something. If you want to spend time debugging it, be my guest: I left the project structure so that you can run `jest` and see what it's complaining about, but you'll need to uncomment out the `describe` statements etc.

Anyway, hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly thorough, detailed response. I sincerely appreciate the amount of thought and effort you put into this. After reviewing your code I realized the problem is the onload event needs to fire after requiring each file -- so there's a much simpler, cleaner solution I'll post shortly. But I couldn't have arrived at it without your help. Thanks.